# Create work item on failure - how to assign to specific user

Tags: build, azure-devops, tfsbuild, workitem

I have a build that is scheduled to run every night. Under "Options" the Option for "Create Work item on failure" is enabled, type is "bug" and the option "Assign to requestor" is checked.

This beeing scheduled, the requestor appears to be "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS". And if a build fails, indeed a new work item is created and assigned to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS".

Obviously, this is *not* one of our normal account, and such the work item, while beeing created, does not end up in anyones list of work items.

So i assume it is need to assign that bug *not* to the requestor, but to a specific user. I don't see an option to do this. Turning off "Assign to requestor" does not help, as it's not possible to specify whom to assign to.

Any ideas how i can make it so, that the created work item is assigned to a specific user?

Comment: @BriteIdea wanted to add a comment but didn't have enough rep so I'm posting it: For future people reading this Question, here is the current reference of Work Item Fields : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify **System.AssignedTo** field in **Additional Fields**.

[image]

Comment: Is there any documentation which other "Additional fields" there are?

Comment: You can get the work item fields through [Work Item Fields REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/fields).

Comment: The link previous referenced has rotted, new link is mentioned in [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840084/create-work-item-on-failure-how-to-assign-to-specific-user#comment123217114_45840084).